# How to left align a whole table in markdown (pandoc)?

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

How do you left align an entire table in Markdown/Pandoc? I know about different ways of specifying tables and how alignment of columns are done, but I cannot find a way to shift the table from center aligned to left aligned (have even tryed embedding `<div style="float: left>..</div>` which didn't work). Do I have to switch to LaTeX to do this? I will export to pdf later on, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited for http://tex.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @DaveJarvis Questions can be on-topic at several SE-sites though. And this question is dealing just as much with markdown as latex. And what about the other 4,432 questions tagged 'latex' at SO?

Comment: Given that a solution was found at TeX SE... Also, SO is about programming. Asking for help with a custom Haskell filter for Pandoc that changes the output document would be programming. Asking for help with how to *use* Pandoc or customise the LaTeX output it generates is more about TeX and software usage than programming. (And I don't have time to scrutinize the other 4k questions, only the ones I find serendipitously.)

Comment: @DaveJarvis The question is on-topic because markdown can also be considered programming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I now found a solution to this problem at [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9707/how-to-left-align-a-table-in-latex). Apparently pandoc inserts `\centering` for every float in the document. This can be cancelled by inserting `\let\centering\relax` in a custom preample to pandoc (as pandoc argument `-H custompreample.tex`). The link also describes more detailed ways to for example define different floats for tables and figures.

Comment: While this will solve your problem, it will prevent *any* element from being centred.  This many not bother you, but it might be a problem for others wanting to use this solution.

Comment: A better solution is to create a custom preamble containing:  `\usepackage{longtable}\setlength{\LTleft}{2em}`.

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to get the solutions here to work--in LaTeX.  I created a new longtable environment to make tables the way I wanted them.  That was easier in the end.  Here's an example Rmd file.

```
---
title: "Custom table"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
output: pdf_document
---

\newenvironment{mylong}
    {\begin{longtable}[l]{p{.25in}p{3in}p{3in}}Line & Statements  & Reasons\\
    \toprule\addlinespace }
    { \addlinespace\bottomrule\end{longtable} }

\begin{mylong} 
1& $a+b=a+d$    & Given P10, if $b=d$, then 1 is true\\
2& $a+b=c$ & Given\\
3& $a+d=c$ & Given P9, if 1 and 2 are true, then 3 is true. QED\\
\end{mylong}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found this solution [here](https://groups.google.com/g/pandoc-discuss/c/X_1tpGufN_w).

a simple `\usepackage` in `header-includes:` that looks doing the job itself...

```
- \usepackage[margins=raggedright]{floatrow}
```

I hope it won't have side effects. Currently, on my pandoc generated pdfs, none, but I don't know its boundaries.

- it has at least one limit: it applies upon every table of your pdf, and not a single one, if it's what you were looking for.