# How to make a pander table keep to the left

Tags: r, r-markdown, tabular, pander

I have searched many places on how to place the whole table to the left but couldn't find a way except to set `floating = FALSE`. The reproducible rmd file is as follows.

````
---
title: "test"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
library(pander)
panderOptions('table.alignment.default', 'left')
panderOptions('table.alignment.rownames', 'left')
pander(mtcars[1:4], caption = "a table")
```
````

The desired output is something like this:

[image]

Comment: This depends on the LaTeX template you are using, see e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21044207/564164). In short, add the required overrides to the preamble, e.g. to disable all `centering` for floats: `\let\centering\relax`.

Comment: I am using Rstudio to knit to pdf. Will try to play around with the template. Thanks for the link!