# Left align the whole table in Markdown (Jupyter)

Tags: pandas, markdown, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am trying to left-align **the whole table** in Markdown (render in JupyterLab). Here is my table:

```
 |      | 0     | 1     |
 |---   |---    |---    |
 | 0    | 2     | 3     |
 | 1    | 4     | 5     |
```

Any suggestions?
I tried solutions suggested in similar posts such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043352/how-to-left-align-a-whole-table-in-markdown-pandoc); none of them worked. If it helps at all, this table is a pandas DataFrame display.

Answer (score 3):

The column justification can be specified using the colon `:` along with the line separator.

For example,

```
|      | Column A | Column B |
|:-----|:---------|:---------|
| 0    | 2        | 3        |
| 1    | 4        | 5        |
```

Produces,

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But I am looking for changing alignment of the table in the screen rather than alignment of table contents. Any hints?

Comment: Nope, what's on the screen comes from the table contents, so not sure how else you'd solve this. @NNsr